# How to display mysql nested json data in multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, nested

How to parse nested JSON data in MySQL? Anyone Kindly help me with that.

Sample JSON Data.

```
    [
  {
    "code": "01",
    "exits": "0",
    "enters": "0",
    "start_time": "00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "code": "01",
    "exits": "0",
    "enters": "0",
    "start_time": "00:15:00"
  },
  {
    "code": "01",
    "exits": "0",
    "enters": "0",
    "start_time": "00:30:00"
  }
]
```

I want to be displayed like.

```
ID     code-start time     code-start time 
1       01-00:00:00        01-00:15:00  .....etc upto 96 columns
```

database Table structure:

```
 id  auto_increment
 json_data  json
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: My Sql Version is 10.4.11-MariaDB